# Programmatically assigning new users to groups

Tags: hooks, organic-groups, users

I have a specific need where if a user is created and assigned to the role "manager" that user should be automatically subscribed to all groups. I can do this without issues if I hard code the uid. I have problems when i use hook_user_insert and I am not sure why. The problem is that none of my code actually executes. The hook does fire when I load a user object of a hard coded uid however.

Here is my hook:

```
 function mm_custom_user_insert(&$edit, &$account, $category)
{

    if(in_array('manager', $account->roles)) {

      //get all gids
      $results = db_query("SELECT gid FROM og");
      $gids= array();
      while($record = $results->fetchAssoc())
      {
        $gids[]= $record['gid'];
      }

      foreach($gids as $gid)
      {
        og_group($gid, array(
                "entity type"       => "user",
                "entity"        => $account,
                "membership type"   => OG_MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_DEFAULT,
            ));
        og_role_grant($gid, $account->uid, 3);  

      }
    }
}
```

My main questions are 
a.) are the user->roles not available at this time? how would I find this out?
b.) could it be that the the uid is not available?

Appreciate the help

Comment: Don't use hook_user_insert to create users... use user_save(), it is much cleaner and you can set everything you want.

Answer (score 1):

The user ID is definitely available, as `hook_user_insert()` is called after the user data has been committed to the database.

I've just put the following code into a test module called `foo`:

```
function foo_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  dpm($account);
}
```

Then I created an account through the admin UI and the output from `dpm()` looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

So as you can see, the roles are available too.

If you're not familiar with the `dpm()` function, it's part of the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). It will print any PHP variable to the standard messages area and will display objects/arrays like the screen shot above. It should help you with most of your debugging needs.

Comment: Thanks Clive, I reviewed the user module to see where the hook was being called and I found that the user roles are available but only by id as they are stored to the user object after the hook.